# Google Sheets: Data Validation - Unique row values across multiple columns

Tags: validation, google-sheets, unique-constraint

Good day,

I have seen from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19927/forcing-uniqueness-in-a-google-spreadsheets-column) a solution to control duplicate entries into a single column. A Data validation with this custom formula works well for one column.

I would like to achieve the same effect over multiple columns ... i.e. unique row entries across multiple columns. Take for example below three columns A-C. Only when values {1,2,1} are entered for the second time will the input be rejected.

```
A          B          C
1          1          1
1          2          1
1          2          2
2          2          2
1          2          1   X Entry should be rejected.
```

Is there a quick way to do this using Data Validation - custom formulae?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use custom formula for data validation:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF($A$1:$A&"×"&$B$1:$B&"×"&$C$1:$C, $A1&"×"&$B1&"×"&$C1)<2)
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. Personally, I would put separators in to make sure that 1 23 4 isn't shown as a duplicate against 1 2 34 (unless you can assume that numbers are single digit).

Comment: I was having trouble with this answer because my unique columns are B,C,D and not A,B,C. I assumed I had to modify the formula to $B1$1:$B, etc., but that broke it. It seems like the columns referenced in the "Criteria" are relative to the "Cell range" selected. TL;DR: you don't need to modify the formula to change the column offsets. Works great!